# EF 6 Eager loading of related data

Tags: entity-framework

I have these model classes:

```
public class ClasseBase
{
    // other properties
    public EnumStato Stato { get; set; }
}

public class Gruppo : ClasseBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties
    
    public virtual ICollection<Livello> Livelli { get; set; }
}

public class Livello : ClasseBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties

    public byte Progressivo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Gruppo))]
    public int IdGruppo { get; set; }
    public Gruppo Gruppo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TariffaOrariaLivello> TariffeOrarie { get; set; }
}

public class TariffaOrariaLivello
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Livello")]
    public int IdLivello { get; set; }
    public Livello Livello { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal StraordinarioDiurno { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal StraordinarioNotturno { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal StraordinarioFestivoNotturno { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DataInizio { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DataFine { get; set; }
}
```

The `DbContext` looks like this:

```
public DbSet<Livello> Livelli { get; set; }
public DbSet<Gruppo> Gruppi { get; set; }
public DbSet<TariffaOrariaLivello> TariffeOrarieLivello { get; set; }
```

I need the list of `TariffeOrarieLivello` with the latest `DataInizio` for those that have `Livello.Stato = Attivo` (active) ordered by `Livello.Progressivo`.

For each `TariffaOrariaLivello`, I need the `Livello` and its related `Gruppo` to be loaded.

I'm using EF 6.

I first wrote this code:

```
var list = db.TariffeOrarieLivello
             .Include(t => t.Livello.Gruppo)
             .Where(t => t.Livello.Stato == Models.Enums.StatoRecord.Attivo)
             .GroupBy(t => t.IdLivello)
             .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DataInizio).FirstOrDefault())
             .ToList();
```

but it doesn't load the `Livello` and `Gruppo`.

After many tries I came up with this code:

```
var alist = db.TariffeOrarieLivello
              .Include(t => t.Livello.Gruppo)
              .Where(t => t.Livello.Stato == Models.Enums.StatoRecord.Attivo)
              .GroupBy(t => t.IdLivello)
              .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.DataInizio)
                            .FirstOrDefault())
              .Select(t => new
                           {
                               t.Id,
                               t.IdLivello,
                               t.StraordinarioDiurno,
                               t.StraordinarioNotturno,
                               t.StraordinarioFestivoNotturno,
                               t.DataInizio,
                               t.DataFine,
                               Livello = t.Livello,
                               Gruppo = t.Livello.Gruppo
                            })
              .ToList();

var thelist = alist
                  .Select(t => new TariffaOrariaLivello()
                       {
                           Id = t.Id,
                           IdLivello = t.IdLivello,
                           StraordinarioDiurno = t.StraordinarioDiurno,
                           StraordinarioNotturno = t.StraordinarioNotturno,
                           StraordinarioFestivoNotturno = t.StraordinarioFestivoNotturno,
                           DataInizio = t.DataInizio,
                           DataFine = t.DataFine,
                           Livello = t.Livello
                       })
                  .ToList();
```

This is the way I found to get a list of `TariffaOrariaLivello`.
Even if it works, I don't like it much.

Can someone tell me if is there another solution without passing through the anonymous object list?

Thanks

Comment: `.Include(t => t.Livello).ThenInclude(l => l.Gruppo)`?

Comment: I'm using EF6.
Isn't ThenInclude for core version? Am I wrong?